# How to call external function which return the json and call from react another component?

Tags: reactjs

```js
import mockRequests from './requests.json'

export const getRequestsSync = () => mockRequests

export const getRequests = () =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(mockRequests), 500)
  })
```

This is Api.js file and export two functions to use in some different class into the react.
How to use this two function into the componentDidMount,I have already imported both of the fucntions into the class.

Comment: Could  you include what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working sample example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-7yqskf?file=Hello.js

You can use it like this:

```
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      getRequestsData: null,
      getRequestsSyncData: null,
    }
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const getRequestsSyncData = getRequestsSync();
    const getRequestsData = await getRequests();

    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return { ...prevState, getRequestsData, getRequestsSyncData }
    }
    )
  }
```